# How avoid upcoming Chrome security errors for SHA-1 certificates if we change the SSL Certificate expiration date

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, certificate, pki

Since that all the HTTPS sites whose certificate chains use SHA-1 and are valid past 1 January 2017 will no longer appear to be fully trustworthy in Chrome’s user interface, I'm looking a way to issue certificates valid only until 31 December 2016.

The Validity of a certificate is handled on the CA server and this is set as a parameter in the CA template, however it accepts periods of time, like months, years or days, you cannot enter a specific date so I wonder if I could write some Powershell script or c# application to run on a daily basis and update the CA template programmatically to make sure that any SSL Cert issued that day is going to expire on 31 December 2016.

Does this make sense and you think it can be achievable?

The CA PKI Server is Windows 2008 R2 and runs in an intranet, we have a web site in c# to submit cert request using the CertEnroll Windows API.

Thanks,

Comment: Why not invest the time you'd spend doing this to upgrade the CA to sha2 instead?

Comment: Or simply spend the time modifying the c# site in order to accept direct entry of expiration dates generally, defaulting to 31 Dec 16.

Comment: @BazzaDP, The team that manages the CA server has been said that they don't have a time frame set yet to build a SHA2 infrastructure. Thanks.

Comment: @SeanBaker, I'm using the CertEnroll COM componet in C# and as per its documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385054(v=vs.85).aspx), the submit method does not handle a parameter to set the expiration date. Do you know any other COM or API that I could use to set the validity time? Thanks.

Comment: @m0dest0 -- I don't, but my understanding was that you have a web application implemented in current state.  If so, my local solution would be to simply translate for the user and submit validity = (submittedDate - currentDate).  Translate it for the user before you hit the MS API.

Comment: @SeanBaker, Validity is not a parameter that could be sent to the CA server, is taken from the CA template which runs on the server. The MS API only accepts name of the CSR, server name and name of the template. Thanks!